# Smoothing a transition matrix

Tags: r, matrix, smoothing, transition-matrix

I have a dataset containing observations at time t and t+1 of ratings A (best) to E (worst) and Default. I want to use transition matrices to predict future ratings t+2, t+3, etc

The transition matrix of the full portfolio is monotonic (transition to a further state is less probable than a transition to a nearer state). However, some sub-portfolios are quite small and therefore not monotonic. This is only due to their size and not a pattern of behavior. All ratings are theoretically possible. Default is an absorbing state. **How can I smooth the matrices? Preferably with an R package as I'm not a mathematician :-)**

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Can you clarify what smoothing you want to do, and relationship between subportfolios

Comment: You could use regularised multinomial regression as provided by ʼglmnetʼ package. This would smooth subportfolios to the total portfolio transition matrix